# Why doesn't it work? A simple SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm new to SQL, I have 3 tables in my database:

- One named `notifications`,
- the other `notifications_log`,
- and the third one is `control`.

Both `notification` and `notification_log` have `notification_id` with pk-fk relation.

There is also another column named `control_id` in `notifications` and I have this column in `control` table too.

Now  what I want to do is to get rows under `description` column of `notification_log` table by connecting `notification` table and `control` table with their `control_id` field. Can you help me with that?

Here's something I've tried:

```
select c.control_name  
  from notifications note, notifications_log note_log, control c 
 where note_log.ALARM_ID = note.ALARM_ID
   and note.CONTROL_ID = C.CONTROL_ID 
  order by control_name desc
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Is there an error or does it not deliver the right data?

Comment: @user1081078, your supplied query joins notification and notification_log on ALARM_ID, but your question says they should be joined on notification_id. Which is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Use JOIN:

```
SELECT c.control_name, note_log.description FROM notifications note
INNER JOIN notifications_log note_log 
    ON note.notification_id = note_log.notification_id
INNER JOIN control c 
    ON note.control_id = c.control_id
ORDER BY c.control_name DESC
```

What you have to understand is if every record in control table has a corresponding record in other tables, otherwise it will not be showed with INNER JOIN.

Comment: thank you Marco, but this returns me no rows. I checked tables and there are related rows on all. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @user1081078: can you edit you question showing us some (related and not) record from your three tables please?

Answer (score 0):

**select description from notification_log where notification_id in (select notification_id from notification)**

if you want to get only the description..

hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds as though you are selecting the wrong field in your query. Try:

```
select distinct note_log.description  
  from notifications note, notifications_log note_log, control c 
 where note_log.notification_id = note.notification_id
   and note.CONTROL_ID = C.CONTROL_ID 
order by 1
```